# Right Arrow Key spontaneously stops working after startup

Tags: keyboard, catalina, hardware, software

### Right Arrow Key spontaneously stops working after startup

---

**Context:**

---

Sometime today, I noticed that my right arrow key was not responding. I first was unable to skip forward 5 seconds on a YouTube video, but thought nothing of it.

Later, I realised I couldn't move right on some text on Safari. I then tried Microsoft Word, Microsoft OneNote, etc. and had the same result: I couldn't move right.

I've checked my shortcuts (based off an Apple forum I read online) but that didn't work. There is nothing blocking the key either (in fact I have a keyboard protector on it).

Also, the <kbd>^ Control</kbd> + <kbd>→ rightarrowkey</kbd> function and the <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>→ rightarrowkey</kbd> function appears to be working (i.e. I can switch desktops using the arrow key and highlight).

---

**Question:**

---

I've honestly got no idea why this has happened. My left arrow key, up and down arrow keys all work. Any ideas to fix this?

---

**Edit 1:**

---

Some more important details:

> *I've noticed, having restarted my computer twice since I asked this question, that upon starting the right arrow key works! I am able to move initially. However, a few minutes later, it simply stops working and I can no longer move right.*

> *I think this means that it is not hardware but software related? Any guidance?*

---

**Edit 2:**

---

> *So at the idea of IconDaemon,I went to System Preferences and checked the "Show Input Menu in Menu bar" button and Voilà! The right arrow key started spontaneously working again! Magic. It worked for the rest of the day and **then died again** when I booted up my laptop. This time the Show Input Menu in Menu bar button magic doesn't work, though it started working for a bit at some random period later... Any ideas?*

---

Comment: First 3 steps: Reboot. Test on a safe boot [shift key at boot]. Test on another user account.

Comment: Do you eat/drink at your computer? For me, sometimes a tiny crumb gets stuck under a key, and initiating some vigourous key-presses pulverizes the crumb to dust. Try that. If you have a can of pressurized air, that sometimes works, too. Coincidentally, the Mute button on my external Apple keyboard has stopped working. The pulverize the crumb trick didn't work for me. :-(

Comment: @Tetsujin I've noted that the right arrow key works on startup, just not after a few minutes. I don't have another user account.

Comment: @IconDaemon it seems to work on a startup which suggests that this is not the solution

Comment: You can create a temporary user account to troubleshoot, and delete it afterwards. Also, in System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources tab, check the "Show Input menu in menu bar" checkbox at the bottom. This'll place a new menu in the menu bar, in which you'll find Show Keyboard Viewer. You can simulate keypresses with this tool. Test this virtual keyboard before and after the physical keyboard's right arrow key stops working. If the virtual keyboard right arrow stops working, too, that's a clue for further research.

Comment: Huh... I went to System Preferences and checked the "Show Input Menu in Menu bar button" and Voilà! The right arrow key has spontaneously started working again! *Magic*. I guess I'll keep track of it over coming days and let you know if it goes off again. Interesting.

Comment: @IconDaemon so it worked for the rest of the day and then died again when I booted up my laptop. This time the Show Input Menu in Menu bar button magic doesn't work.